# Why is a button submitting a form even when I set the type to button (rather than submit)?

Tags: javascript, html

Click on "Add another start and end time." Notice that the "Remove this segments." buttons are behaving as if their types are not being changed. I ran this through JSLint without any issues and I'm not getting errors in the console. Using the web developer tools in Chrome, it looks like it's type attribute isn't getting set. I can't figure out what's going on.

http://jsfiddle.net/gtr053/xtGPR/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox says:

> Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount"  code: "1" nsresult: "0x80530001 (NS_ERROR_DOM_INDEX_SIZE_ERR)"  location: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/gtr053/xtGPR/show/ Line: 39"]

Line 39 is:

```
document.getElementById('start_end_times').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].deleteRow(index);
```

So presumably index is wrong.

Comment: Ah. Changed `removeButton.onclick = function () {removeStartEndTime(removeButton.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex); };` to `removeButton.onclick = function () {removeStartEndTime(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex - 1); };` Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't getting any errors until I threw it into jsFiddle for some reason. :/